# Using Python's Loop Functions

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to stop the for loop based on the variable *numOfEmp*. For example, if I input 2 into numOfEmp, I expect the loop to run two times, showing the statement "Enter Employee's ID" and "Enter Employee's Name" twice, respectively. However, with this code that I have, the loop continues to appear "Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): " after two times (my anticipation). This is the code I have, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
#Ask how many employees are there
numOfEmp = int(input("How many employee are in this week's payroll: "))

#Input validation
while numOfEmp < 0:
    print ('Sorry, illegal input! Please input again.')
    numOfEmp = int(input("How many employee are in this week's payroll: "))
    
#Input validation
while numOfEmp == 0:
    print ("NO PAYROLL? Great! Goodbye.")
    break

while numOfEmp > 0: #Ask for each employee's detail
    for program in range (numOfEmp):
        print () #Divider line
        empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
        empName = input ("Enter Employee's Name: ")
```

Please let me know if I format this wrongly!

---

Example output page: (asterisk is input)

```
How many employee are in this week's payroll: **2**
Enter Employee's ID (i.e. AF101): **AS111**
Enter Employee's Name: **First Last**

Enter Employee's ID (i.e. AF101): **AS111**
Enter Employee's Name: **First Last**

Enter Employee's ID (i.e. AF101): **AS111**
Enter Employee's Name: **First Last**

[and so on]
```

Comment: Can you add the input and output so we can see what happened?

Comment: The logic of your code is way to off. There is no need for the second `while` as you can replace it by a `if` statement. Also the second `while` is totally redundant. It is causing an infinite loop which never ends as the `numOfEmp` is always greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think just removing the while would work:

```py
while numOfEmp > 0: #Ask for each employee's detail
    for program in range (numOfEmp):
        print () #Divider line
        empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
        empName = input ("Enter Employee's Name: ")
```

Should become ->

```py
for program in range(numOfEmp):
    print () #Divider line
    empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
    empName = input ("Enter Employee's Name: ")
```

The for i in range iterates over all values from 0 to the stop value (exclusive). Find more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the last while loop. It is gonna run forever since the `numOfEmp` isn't being decremented at all. You need to decrement `numOfEmp` by one for each iteration like so:

```
while numOfEmp > 0: #Ask for each employee's detail
    for program in range (numOfEmp):
        print () #Divider line
        empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
        empName = input ("Enter Employee's Name: ")
        numOfEmp -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that while numOfEmp > 0: is always true

One solution is changing the value of numOfEmp after the for loop finishes

```
while numOfEmp > 0: #Ask for each employee's detail
    for program in range (numOfEmp):
        print () #Divider line
        empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
        empName = input ("Enter Employee's Name: ")
    numOfEmp = -1
```

A better solution might be to simply use if instead of while

```
if numOfEmp > 0: #Ask for each employee's detail
    for program in range (numOfEmp):
        print () #Divider line
        empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
        empName = input ("Enter Employee's Name: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your numOfEmp is not decreasing anywhere in this while loop:

```
while numOfEmp > 0: #Ask for each employee's detail
    for program in range (numOfEmp):
        print () #Divider line
        empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
        empName = input ("Enter Employee's Name: ")
```

That's why the program is prompting for input forever. Just decrease the value of numOfEmp after each iteration, if you do not want to change your code that much:

```
while numOfEmp > 0: #Ask for each employee's detail
    for program in range (numOfEmp):
        print () #Divider line
        empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
        empName = input ("Enter Employee's Name: ")
    numOfEmp=-1
```

Apart from that fix, you can simplify the whole input process like this:

```
#Input & Corresponding validation
while True:
    numOfEmp = int(input("How many employee are in this week's payroll: "))
    if numOfEmp < 0:
        print ('Sorry, illegal input! Please input again.')
        continue
    elif numOfEmp == 0:
        print ("NO PAYROLL? Great! Goodbye.")
        break
    else:
        for program in range (numOfEmp):
            print () #Divider line
            empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
            empName = input ("Enter Employee's Name: ")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding `break` to the last `while` loop

```
# Ask how many employees are there
numOfEmp = int(input("How many employee are in this week's payroll: "))

# Input validation
while numOfEmp < 0:
    print('Sorry, illegal input! Please input again.')
    numOfEmp = int(input("How many employee are in this week's payroll: "))

# Input validation
while numOfEmp == 0:
    print("NO PAYROLL? Great! Goodbye.")
    break

while numOfEmp > 0:  # Ask for each employee's detail
    for program in range(numOfEmp):
        print()  # Divider line
        empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
        empName = input("Enter Employee's Name: ")
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the while loops and make one single while loop which runs based on inputs -

```
while True:
    numOfEmp = int(input("How many employees are in this week's payroll: "))

    if numOfEmp < 0:
        print ('Sorry, illegal input! Please input again.')

    elif numOfEmp == 0:
        print ("NO PAYROLL? Great! Goodbye.")
        break

    else:
        for i in range(numOfEmp):
            print()
            empID = input("Enter Employee's ID(i.e. AF101): ")
            empName = input("Enter Employee's Name: ")
        break
```